# Wrapping Wordpress text content in .class

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to wrap JUST the text content in a class from my WordPress post. Basically anything that isn't wrapped in an `<img>` tag.

I've tried

```
function sr_wrap_content_in_div( $content ) {
    $contents = explode("<img", $content);

    foreach($contents as $content) {
        $before_tag = strstr($content, '/>', true); 
        $after_tag = strstr($content, '/>');
        if( $before_tag == '' && $after_tag == '' ) {
            echo '<div class="content-wrap">' . $content . '</div></div>'; // change it later if you need to
        } else if( $after_tag == '/> ' ) {
            echo '<img' . $before_tag . '/>';
        } else {
            echo '<img' . $before_tag . '/>' . '<div class="content-wrap">' . substr($after_tag, 2) . '</div></div>'; // change here too.
        }
}
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sr_wrap_content_in_div' );
```

Which comes close. It wraps the content but it also wraps empty space between any images.

Comment: If the reason you're doing this is for styling, there is DEFINITELY a better way to accomplish this. Can you explain the 'why' of what you're trying to do, so we might be able to suggest a better way to approach?

Comment: I want to wrap the content in my wordpress post so I can apply specific padding/margins to the text. But I don't want the class aplied to the images. I want the text to be 'pushed away' from the images but the images close together. I don't have control over where/how many images and text. But they are full size images (full width)

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing you'd want to do via stylesheets. I'll post as an answer so I can use more formatting, etc.

Comment: Problem with stylesheets is I can target each individual <p> or <blockquote> etc. But I want the padding to be on a container wrapping them so I can apply different padding to the paragraphs themselves

Comment: Hmm... Not 100% sure I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but I guarantee there's a way to do it with stylesheets. The approach above will lead to nothing but trouble, I promise :)  Do you have a URL you can show us for an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, It is on my local server. I just want to wrap all the text in a class (I am using bootstrap framework so wrapping them in .col tags would be preferable) I just want the images left alone and the content wraped so I can apply padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation above, this is the type of thing that stylesheets are built for. No muddying HTML up with extra classes, etc.

So first step, find out what div or wrapper element contains all of your test. Probably `<div class='content'>` or, `<div id='main'>` or something like that.

Then, in your theme's stylesheet, do something like this:

```
div#main p{padding:0 20px;}
div#main p + img{margin-top:30px}
```

That last one applies a top margin of 30px to any image that's immediately following a paragraph, which sounds like what you have in mind.

Comment: That is one way to go at it ya, I never thought of doing it that way. My concern is that I don't know the order of the content of the posts. Sometimes there may be content above or below an image, or certain images in a row etc. I figured it was easier to pull the text out and try to wrap it

Comment: The other problem is that I can't target elements right BEFORE images this way

Comment: If you can tell me specifically what you're trying to accomplish, maybe I can help out. If you're looking to adjust margin if before an image, it'd seem that you could just adjust the margin-top on the image instead, no?

Answer (score 0):

Well my answer will be go with stylesheets as all are saying,

As per my understanding of the problem you have, the problem you are facing is that it is on local server but I will see it as an opportunity.

You can check the temporary interface for stylesheet is debug window. You can get this window by pressing f12 key on the webpage and will open element inspector for you. Now go to the elements section of this window and you will see all the elements in the page on left-side section and the styles in the right-side section, you can there apply some styles temporarily to see the result, as soon as you are satisfied with style you applied paste that in your main stylesheet and that is done.

I will suggest that this is the most efficient way and less time consuming method. try it if you like.

Comment: Stylesheets work, I just don't have control of the content (it's a theme for another author) so I don't know the text/image order or content. Doing style sheets seems like it would work but trying to figure out the most foolproof way

Comment: You can use the inspect element tool as specified above to decide the order of text/image, complete the experiment and if you do/can not access that theme write a plugin to insert your stylesheet to override, thats all.